# Rounding - Dozens

Tags: java, android, double

I'm starting at the android and java now, and I have a problem.

```
I have a result x = 206.0548.
And y = 206, both of type double
How do I get the result is always rounded up to 210?

In other cases, assuming x = 203.5231 I wanted to round to 205.
If x = 201 to 205 round off.
If x = 198.25 round off to 200.
```

... thank you

Comment: So you want to round in steps of 5? Only valid results would be 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, ...?

Comment: What about values between 200 and 201?

Comment: round as the zapl said, every 5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Math.ceil(x/5) * 5;
I think. Look up the Math.ceil method as that is the best way to go.